# OAuth2 Window Closing

Tags: wordpress, oauth-2.0

First question and I am by far not a developer. I am trying to authorise a plugin from WordPress to my Google Analytics account. When I press the "Allow" button it proceeds to open up the window and display the code needed that I need to copy and paste back to the plugin field. The problem is though that the window closes in less than a second so I have no chance of grabbing the code. Any help gladly received, thanks Jason

Comment: Clear cookies, maybe you are just logged in?

Comment: Did that, logged out as cleared cookies, logged in again, also checked and double checked that accounts.google.com was allowed in pop up exceptions, but no joy :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue earlier today.

I ended up logging in via Microsoft Edge, and it worked fine (to save time, I just pasted in the URL I was at before it would close on Chrome).

The window stayed open so I could grab the code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for trying to offer some help. I hope it's at least a temporary solution to the author's problem.

Comment: Yes many thanks @Rafaello this did the trick, whilst not solving the bug its a good work around... :)